# Parsing function in haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I'm new to Haskell and I am trying to parse expressions. I found out about Parsec and I also found some articles but I don't seem to understand what I have to do. My problem is that I want to give an expression like "x^2+2*x+3" and the result to be a function that takes an argument x and returns a value. I am very sorry if this is an easy question but I really need some help. Thanks! The code I inserted is from the article that you can find on [this link](http://www.cs.lth.se/EDA120/assignment4/parser.pdf).

```
import Control.Monad(liftM)
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec 
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Expr  
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Token  
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Language  

data Expr = Num Int       | Var String    | Add Expr Expr
          | Sub Expr Expr | Mul Expr Expr | Div Expr Expr
          | Pow Expr Expr
          deriving Show

expr :: Parser Expr
expr = buildExpressionParser table factor
    <?> "expression"

table = [[op "^" Pow AssocRight],
         [op "*" Mul AssocLeft, op "/" Div AssocLeft],
         [op "+" Add AssocLeft, op "-" Sub AssocLeft]]
    where
        op s f assoc
            = Infix (do{ string s; return f}) assoc
factor = do{ char '('
        ; x <- expr
        ; char ')'
        ; return x}
    <|> number
    <|> variable
    <?> "simple expression"

number :: Parser Expr
number = do{ ds<- many1 digit
        ; return (Num (read ds))}
    <?> "number"

variable :: Parser Expr
variable = do{ ds<- many1 letter
        ; return (Var ds)}
    <?> "variable"
```

Comment: I have something that I found in some articles but it is ok to post it even if is not my own?

Comment: please do post it as others may find it useful as well.  Be sure to include a link to the original source.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is just a parser for expressions with variables. Actually interpreting the expression is an entirely separate matter.

You should create a function that takes an already parsed expression and values for variables, and returns the result of evaluating the expression. Pseudocode:

```
evaluate :: Expr -> Map String Int -> Int
evaluate (Num n) _ = n
evaluate (Var x) vars = {- Look up the value of x in vars -}
evaluate (Plus e f) vars = {- Evaluate e and f, and return their sum -}
...
```

I've deliberately omitted some details; hopefully by exploring the missing parts, you learn more about Haskell.

As a next step, you should probably look at the `Reader` monad for a convenient way to pass the variable map `vars` around, and using `Maybe` or `Error` to signal errors, e.g. referencing a variable that is not bound in `vars`, or division by zero.